# Subtotal and Countif combined on filtered data

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to do a calculation on filtered data? In this case filter the data by year and calculate the "No of Bookings made less than x days before check-in" where x = D4 e.g. 100

I'm using 365.  Filter data by F6 (Check-In year).  In C4 display the number of bookings made less than the value of D4

[image: Example]

I sort the data on F6 "Check-In year" these work.
In B2 I have `=SUBTOTAL(103,A7:A240)`
In F2 I have `=SUBTOTAL(109,D7:D240)/B2`

I've tried `=COUNTIF(D7:D240,"<10")` and `=SUBTOTAL(3,D7:D240)<10`, but my knowledge of SubTotal and Count if is limited I'm afraid.  Hope someone might know.

Comment: ,,, if you are using higher version of Excel like 2021 or 365 then is possible,,, please [edit] your post & confirm then I'll show you how !! Also confirm what you would like to FILTER (data Range,, along with conditions).

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. posted updated.

Comment: ,,, check my post has possible solution,,, in case of any further issue,, write COMMENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Rajesh.  The correct answer is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(D7:D16,ROW(D7:D16)-MIN(ROW(D7:D16)),,1))*(D7:D16>=D4))
```

On YouTube I found "How can you use COUNTIF to analyze only the visible rows from a filtered data set?"

thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not repost other peoples answer, if their answer worked for you, accept it instead. This way somebody else that finds your question knows that it worked for you, instead of having to look at the usernames.

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat**

*This solution is based on information posted by the OP above.*

I'm assuming that your data set is in `A7:F15`, *you may adjust this accordingly.*

- Your first requirement is COUNT booking less than the benchmark in
  D4.

This can be calculated using COUNIF or SUMPRODUCT.

`=COUNTIF(D7:D15,"<"&D4)`

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(D7:D15<D4))`

- If you want to filter other data then use this:

  `=FILTER(A7:F15,D7:D15<D4,"")`
- This will filter all records where Nu. of days are less than D4.

Another is,

`=FILTER(A7:F15,(D7:D15<D4)*(F7:F15=2019),"")`

- This will filter all records where Nu. of days are less than D4 and year is 2019 or what so ever.

*If you want Summary then try this.*

A20:  `=UNIQUE(F7:F15)`

- Then in adjacent cell.

  B20: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(D7:D15<$D$4)*(F7:F15=A20))`

**N.B.** *Adjust cell references as needed.*

Comment: Thanks again Rajesh for the detailed feedback.  Your formula's work only on non filtered data.  My requirement is to run the formula on filtered data e.g. Automatically  run the formula on the filtered data e.g. without having to manually define the year.

Comment: @Tmc_m ,,, look getting total on filter data is like SUBTOTAL,,,, and to atomize all that the best possible method is VBA macro,,,, or the SUBTOTAL & GROUP command,, or Pivot Table !!